# Dropping Frames when Playing back Sped Up Footage in PP CC 2018

Tags: premiere, framerate, playback, performance

My playback of footage that is sped up 500% is awful in PP CC 2018 on my desktop but fine on my laptop. My CPU utilization is not maxing out on my desktop but I'm still dropping 90% of my frames. I'm using 1/4 resolution for playback, have plenty of memory allocated to PP, have memory usage set to "performance", etc.

Desktop specs:
6700K
32GB 3200Mhz 
GTX1070

My laptops specs are not as good but seems to be fine with the playback of the exact same timeline. I'm curious if there's something I'm forgetting or not thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so already, you might need to pre-render the time adjusted clip.

Select your clip(s) and from the top menu bar select "*Sequence > Render Selection*".

The green bar above your tracks will indicate that the selection should run at real time during playback as you have preview files store in memory.

[image]